# how to generate ethereum qr code address with amount?

Tags: php, qr-code, payment, bitcoin, coinpayments-api

I working on coinpayment gateway I want to generate qr code with address and amount.
How to pass amount in google chart api with address?

This code is perfect working for bitcoin:

```
<img width="220" height="220" src="https://blockchain.info/qr?data=ethereum:<?php echo $result['result']['address']; ?>?amount=<?php echo $result['result']['amount']; ?>%26label=example%2520label">
```

But these both are not getting amount with address

```
<center><img width="220" height="220" alt="bitcoin" src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=500x500&chl=Ethereum:<?php echo $result['result']['address']; ?>&chld=H|0"></center>

<center><img width="220" height="220" alt="bitcoin" src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl=ethereum:0x<?php echo $result['result']['address']; ?>&choe=UTF-8"></center>`
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's impossible, because even big coin accepting sites like "coinpayments.net" 's qr payment code doesn't include the amount. (But if paid with bitcoin or other currency it does.) Sorry to let you down but the best you could do is

```
src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300&300&chld=L|2&cht=qr&chl=ethereum:<?php echo $result['result']['address']; ?>"
```

the link will look somthing like

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=225x225&chld=L|2&cht=qr&chl=ethereum:0x9610a371F94BE34D4D0CB9c35D621d657133c0e5
```

no one seems to include their amount...

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully implemented this package:
[ethereum-qr-code](https://github.com/jibrelnetwork/ethereum-qr-code).

It implements the [EIP67 standard](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/67) which uses a `value` field for the amount-to-pay and an `ethereum` field for the ETH address.

However, actual usage of the QR protocol is currently **very fractured** and gives different and unexpected results based on which wallet the user uses.

Some problems we have found with some Ethereum wallets:

- *imToken*, *BRD wallet*, *Lykke* require a QR field: `amount` to be `ETH`
- *Trust wallet* requires a QR field: `amount` to be `wei` instead of ETH!
- *Toshi wallet* crashes on QR code scan (at time of writing 2018-07-24)
- None of the wallets we tried use the `value` field...

I have requested the feature to add the option of `amount` on Github [here](https://github.com/jibrelnetwork/ethereum-qr-code/issues/27). And I have myself forked the package [here](https://github.com/DRI-network/ethereum-qr-code) and changed the field called `value` to `amount`.

Answer (score 0):

There is obviously no standard since it's decentralized but the format I have seen used a lot (including by coinbase) is this: `ethereum:{0xAddress}?value={wei}` without the curly brackets of course

Answer (score -1):

You can't include the USD amount, but you certainly can include the BTC amount in the QR code. The QR code essentially embeds a text like this:

bitcoin:1ArmoryXcfq7TnCSuZa9fQjRYwJ4bkRKfv?amount=0.005
Note the amount here is the amount in BTC. You can generate a QR code for that text using gobitcoin.io. If you just want to insert an image, you can use googleapi.com to generate it. For example, a URL like this:

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl=bitcoin:1ArmoryXcfq7TnCSuZa9fQjRYwJ4bkRKfv?&amount=0.005